# Import indexes from MongoDB v2.4 to MonDB v3.6.4

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6, mongodb2.4

I have migrated the `collection.bson` file from **MongoDB 2.4** to **MongoDB 3.6.4** as `collection.json`.

But their is 1 more file `collection.metadata.json` in **MongoDB 2.4**.

How can I import this to **MongoDB 3.6.4**?

content of `collection.metadata.json` is as below;

```
{
  "options": {
    "create": "collection"
  },
  "indexes": [
    {
      "v": 1,
      "name": "_id_",
      "key": {
        "_id": 1
      },
      "ns": "emgda.collection"
    },
    {
      "v": 1,
      "name": "customerId_1_elementId_1_siteId_1_createdTimestamp_1",
      "key": {
        "customerId": 1,
        "elementId": 1,
        "siteId": 1,
        "createdTimestamp": 1
      },
      "ns": "emgda.collection",
      "background": true,
      "sparse": true
    }
  ]
}
```

> mongorestore version is as below,

```
emgda@ubuntu:~/trial$ mongorestore --version
mongorestore version: r3.6.4
git version: d0181a711f7e7f39e60b5aeb1dc7097bf6ae5856
Go version: go1.7
   os: linux
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

> NOTE: When I use `mongoretore -d emgda auditing.bson`, I get below error for the collection.

```
checking for collection data in auditing.bson
reading metadata for emgda.auditing from auditing.metadata.json
Failed: emgda.auditing: error creating collection emgda.auditing: error running create command: BSON field 'OperationSessionInfo.create' is a duplicate field
```

Comment: How did you import `collection.bson` into MongoDB -- you mention importing as `collection.json`? If you imported using `mongorestore`, the associated metadata file should have been processed. If the secondary index wasn't created, the most straightforward approach would be to connect to the target database (`emgda`?) using the `mongo` shell and then build the index in the background with the same options: `db.collection.createIndex({"customerId": 1, "elementId": 1, "siteId": 1, "createdTimestamp": 1}, { background:true, sparse: true})`.

Comment: @Stennie: Updated my post with error that I get when I directly use `mongorestore`

Comment: @AnkurSoni, Could you update mongorestore command, through which you are going to restore the **collection.bson** dump file.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the output `mongorestore --version`? Do you know what version of `mongodump` was used?  The error message indicates the collection `create` option is being passed twice, so I expect deleting the line `"create": "collection"` will  allow your version of `mongorestore` to process the metadata.json.

Comment: @stennie: updated

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan: done. please check the post.

Comment: @AnkurSoni, did you try the command like  mongoretore **--db** emgda auditing.bson; In place of -d can you use the --db then database name then path of your collection.bson file.

Comment: Yes, but same error.

Comment: @AnkurSoni, As per your error it seems like that you are going to create collection in emgda database , which is already exist. you have to mention the **--drop** in the mongorestore command as **mongoretore  --drop --d emgda auditing.bson**;

Comment: Still it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually remove `"options": { "create": "collection" },` from `*.metadata.json` file and rest worked fine.